# gnupg encrypt not working with other public key

Tags: gpg

I'm using gnupg package and trying to encrypt and sign the csv file by encrypting other public keys (file receiver public key) and signing with my private key. But the file can't decrypt to other user (file receiver). It's said decryption failed. Can someone guide me it is possible to do this?

gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12
libgcrypt 1.8.4
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /root/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact command that you use for encryption, as well as the command the other person uses for decryption, along with the verbatim output of each command.

Comment: About _/root/.gnupg_, generally it is better to run anything not requiring root access (for example, **gpg**) as a regular user.